# angular 2 countup timer

Tags: angular, typescript

Can some one give me count-up timer example in angular and thanks in advance

I have this TypeScript code when I add this to my project nothing happens

```ts
var minutesLabel = document.getElementById("minutes");
var secondsLabel = document.getElementById("seconds");
var totalSeconds = 0;
setInterval(setTime, 1000);

function setTime() {
    ++totalSeconds;
    secondsLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalSeconds%60);
    minutesLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds/60));
}

function pad(val) {
    var valString = val + "";
    if(valString.length < 2) {
        return "0" + valString;
    } else {
        return valString;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how did you try to integrate this code in your angular project instead and also to show the problem you face with the integration?

Comment: i add that code to html with <b><b id="minutes">00</b>:<b id="seconds">00</b></b>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this directive provided by "siddii"
https://siddii.github.io/angular-timer/

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you aren't doing it the Angular2 way.
You are currently modifying the DOM directly using the `document` property. Yet this is a bad habit and you should do this using the build in Components and Viewbindings Angular2 supports. Instead of doing stuff like `secondsLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalSeconds%60);`, just use properties that you bind to your view, then it should work.